# How to show Lightning Record Page in the Salesforce App?

Tags: mobile, lightning-app-builder

I am playing around with the Lightning App Builder and would like a record page to show in the Salesforce Mobile App. However after trying for a while my changes are not reflected on the mobile, only on desktop. Hope you can help.

The page is activated as the org default for both phone and desktop. As you can see below this is what I expect to see in the app, but it just uses the standard look.

[image: From the Lightning App Builder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Lightning Experience in the mobile app yet, it's only available in the mobile browser for now.  LEX is supposed to be released to the mobile app in Winter 20.  There is a pilot program available now -- you'll have to contact your Salesforce account executive to apply to it.

See the [Lightning Experience for Salesforce Mobile App](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-experience-for-salesforce-mobile-app/get-to-know-the-new-mobile-app) for more info.

Comment: Funny how you can switch to the Mobile view and not display it like that on the mobile... Will wait for winter 20 :) Thx.